# Has Anyone Used Crowd 2.2.7 With Spring Security 3.0 For SSO Implementation?

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

Has anyone used [crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/) 2.2.7 with spring security 3.0 for SSO implementation?

Is there any better alternative in open source?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Could you share? thanks.

Comment: See [Integrating Crowd with Spring Security](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Integrating+Crowd+with+Spring+Security) for documentation.